# Resumable large file (2+Gb) upload over web

Tags: php, perl, file-upload, upload, resume

I'd like to implement large file upload, there are **so many solutions** out there (jquery, php, flash, java, js/jquery, node.js, etc...) that I quickly got lost / couldn't really find something that meet my requirements.

Basically I need this:

1. I must be able to handle large, 2GB+, files
2. I must be able to pause/resume upload if connection temporarily drops out
3. Progress indicator
4. Good cross-browser support
5. Easy to install/update/maintain/use
6. Multiple/concurrent upload support
7. I don't need encoding, unzip, etc...I just need the upload feature
8. I'm open when it comes to technology (also, see next point), as long as I can run it on an EC2 linux instance (standard amazon linux distribution)
9. I know that I'm ruling out an important technology, but I'd like to avoid java applet due to poor install rate of the java runtime in the market that I'm targeting

Worth mentioning libraries includes [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and [node.js library called formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) which seems to (almost?) meet my need. Plupload has all the features that I need, except that it seems to have issues with 2GB+ files

Thanks!

PS. I'm so desperate that even **commercial components are OK**!

Comment: Most solutions for older browsers will use the built-in file browser/uploader, which is NOT resumable. If you need pause/resume, the uploader will need to use HTML 5 support for reading local files, which only works in newer browsers. Even with this you will need a backend solution since the usual file receiver code works with the old browser upload code.  For the HTML 5 browser file reader API see:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0):

We had outstanding success with [swfupload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/), and here's a [demo](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm).  Our clients upload HD video files, and this component was a snap to get in and running with our customizations.

Comment: *2. I must be able to pause/resume upload if connection temporarily drops out.* It seems swfupload doest not support this feature?

Comment: @GDP is swfupload able to upload a file that has size more then 2gb ?

Comment: @Harshil Shah - I beliece so, but can't say for sure.  We upload 15 minute videos, but they're all H.264, so we've not reached that limit.

Comment: @GDP Do u know any other free tools that supports file upload for 2GB+ zip file?